# How to decompile this x87 assembly calculation?

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, reverse-engineering, x87

The program I'm reversing does simple multiplication between float number and 8 byte integer:

```
section .data

va: dt 1.4426950408889634074
vb: dd 0x42424242
    dd 0x41414141

section .text
global main

main:
    fld tword[va]
    fmul qword[vb]
    ret
```

Result under gdb:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x08048360 in main ()
(gdb) x/i $eip
0x8048360 <main>:       fld    TBYTE PTR ds:0x804953c
0x8048366 <main+6>:     fmul   QWORD PTR ds:0x8049546
0x804836c <main+12>:    ret
(gdb) x/gx 0x8049546
0x8049546 <vb>: 0x4141414142424242
(gdb) si
0x08048366 in main ()
0x0804836c in main ()
(gdb) info float
=>R7: Valid   0x4014c726039c95268dc4 +3262848.902912714389
```

I'm trying to recreate this program in C (same 32bit environment):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned long long vb = 0x4141414142424242LL;
    float r, va = 1.4426950408889634074F;

    r = va * vb;
    printf("%f\n", r);
}
```

...but I get very different results:

```
$ ./test
6783712964982603776.000000
```

What I'm doing wrong in my C program?

Comment: x87 is a floating point-related subset of the x86 architecture instruction set. => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87

Comment: @m0skit0 One better than a x86, of course.

Comment: 0x4141414142424242 x 1.4426950408889634074 is definitely 6783712964982603776.000000, not 3262848.902912714389.

Comment: @m0skit0: If you were that old as your profile-image implies, you should know ;-)

Comment: @Olaf In fact I knew because I even had a 387 I just got confused by the notation :^P

Comment: @m0skit0: 386/387 is still pretty young.

Answer (score 8):

In the asm code you're actually multiplying two `double`s with the `fmul` instruction, not a `float` and an `int`. To do something similar in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t vbi = 0x4141414142424242ULL; // hex representation of double
    double r, vb, va = 1.4426950408889634074;

    memcpy(&vb, &vbi, sizeof(vb));        // copy hex to double
    r = va * vb;
    printf("va = %f, vb = %f, r = %f\n", va, vb, r);
    return 0;
}
```

Result = `va = 1.442695, vb = 2261634.517647, r = 3262848.902913`.

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/mA3Fld)</kbd>

Comment: This assumes `long long int` and `double` have the same width. Can that be safely made?

Comment: OK - it's only for illustration purposes, but to keep everyone happy I'll change it to `uint64_t`.

Comment: @MCan : If this answer solved you problem and was useful, please consider accepting it as an answer. You can find out more about the hows and whys of answering questions on SO here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 3):

This assembler code is not doing what you think it is doing:

```
main:
    fld tword[va]
    fmul qword[vb]
    ret
```

You suggest *simple multiplication between float number and 8 byte integer* . This is actually multiplication of a 10-byte extended double floating point value by the 8-byte double (not 8-byte integer) represented by 0x4141414142424242 . 0x4141414142424242 is treated as the bits of an 8-byte double floating point value by your code, not an 8-byte integer converted to a double floating point value.

The code for what you believed was happening could have looked something like:

```
main:
    fild qword[vb]     ; Convert 64-bit integer to an extended precision double in st0
    fld tword[va]      ; st(0)=>st(1) st(0) = 10-byte float(va)
    fmulp              ; Multiply st(0) and st(1). Result in st(0).
```

This just clears up your misinterpretation of the assembler code.